# How do I bend a 2D Mesh with or without more than one armature?

Tags: animation, mesh, bones

[image: straight][image: ben]

As you can see I had no problems bending a 3d mesh with 2 bones, but I had no such luck with 2D animation I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to make a wing flap for my animation. I want the wing to bend in an up and down motion when I animate it, but first the mesh needs to be able to bend.

As you can see I had no problems bending a 3D pipe object with 2 armature bones in pose mode, but had no such luck with a 2D mesh

Or is it possible to bend a mesh with a single bone? or in other words can you bend an armature bone?

Normally when you want to bend an object you would need 2 or more armature bones.parent the bones to the mesh, then put weight on the mesh etc . I'm trying to do that with a 2D mesh but not having much success

Comment: Please could you provide some clarification? Perhaps draw a few frames by hand to indicate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Without knowing anything more, I would say check your vertex groups on the 2D mesh. Bones work the same (and can deform 2d objects) as a 3D mesh.

Comment: You should provide picture of what is not working, instead of the 3D bending which works : these pictures give no information about your question

Comment: I cant add more than 2 pics I'm afraid

Comment: Ive tried added weights to different vertex groups. not having luck. if i rotate one part of the mesh with its armature it does an rotation and gets smaller if  i try rotate it  in the slightest

Comment: definitely, you should upload your file as this is not easy at all to understand from what you are starting here. Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/